# Can WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 run with JRE only?

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

Can WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 be run with only JRE (without JDK)? The server can start up successfully but I am not sure about the runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need fully JDK to run the product., JRE is enough. It's mentioned in the [Installation Prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Installation+Prerequisites)

> Oracle and IBM JRE 1.7 are also supported when running (not building)
>   WSO2 products.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WSO2 Official Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Installation+Prerequisites) , it requires JDK as well.3

## Update:

I think I have misunderstood the documentation, seems like it says JRE is enough for running the product.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this information on the same page. Oracle and IBM JRE 1.7 are also supported when running (not building) WSO2 products.

Comment: I suggest you to go ahead, if you came up with any issues, you can raise them here or in dev@wso2.org mailing list